# How to pass text field value from jsp to java class

Tags: java, html, jsp

How to pass text field value from jsp to java class.

my **.jsp** code is

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <FORM>
        Please enter your name:
        <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="text1">
        <BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
    </FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

my **.java** class code is

here in string str i need to get the textfield value.

```
class sample{

    String str="";    //C:/check/svntes

    File exportDir = new File(str);
    if (exportDir.exists()) {
        SVNErrorMessage err = SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorCode.IO_ERROR, "Path ''{0}'' already exists", exportDir);
        throw new SVNException(err);
    }
    exportDir.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: Change your Java class to be a `Servlet`, and then the target in your JSP to post to the URL you configure for the Servlet....

Comment: What are you trying to do by reading using the File api ? What connection does it have to the JSP ?

Comment: you have to pass the string to servlet them to java class(by parameters) as the string you are passing is a form field .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm .. let's assume how your jsp & java file interact with each other. Correct if im wrong.

### A.jsp file

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<FORM  ACTION="B.JSP" METHOD="POST"> //edited part
        Please enter your name:
        <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="text1">
        <BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
    </FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

### B.JSP

```
<jsp:useBean id="sample" scope="page" class="com.home.file.sample" /> // sample is java file name

String name = request.getParameter("text1");
int iRowAffected = 0;   

//-------now pass parameter "name" to your sample java file

sample.function_name("name");
```

### Sample.java

```
public class sample
{

   public int function_name(String NAME)
   { 

     String str = NAME;

     File exportDir = new File(str);
     if (exportDir.exists()) {
         SVNErrorMessage err = SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorCode.IO_ERROR,        "Path ''{0}'' already exists", exportDir);
         throw new SVNException(err);
     }
     exportDir.mkdirs();

     //continue with your coding 

   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

To passing value from JSP to Java, you need java `Servlet`.

Call servet from `form` tag and then get value using `request.getParameter("your value")` api of `request` object.

JSP Page:

```
<form action="HelloServlet" method="POST"> 
  Please enter your name:
 <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Servlet :

```
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet { 
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
 throws ServletException, IOException { 

 // reading the user input  
 String text1= request.getParameter("text1"); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your java class a servlet?

Because then you need to post to your servlet like this:

```
<form action="ServletName" method="GET">
    Please enter your name: 
    <input type="text" name="text1" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then in your servlet you can get the string value like this:

```
String str = request.getParameter("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

**name.jsp**

```
<FORM  action="/submitName" method="get">
        Please enter your name:
        <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="text1">
        <BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
    </FORM>
```

First of all, in your above jsp file two things are missing **action** 
and **method**(optional, by default it takes "get") attributes.

Now to get the input value in you java class, you need to write a **Servlet** class and configure it in the **web.xml** with a url mapping **"/submitName"**.

**MyServlet.java**

```
// Import required java libraries

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
  {
      String name = request.getParameter("text1"); //should be same name as form input name
      System.out.println(name);
  }           
}
```

**web.xml** will be as follows,

```
<web-app>  

<servlet>  
<servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/submitName</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  

<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>name.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>  

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got answer by this way..Its working fine.

```
my.jsp code:

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


</head>
<body>
<form >
Enter the word: <input type="text" name="word">
<input type="submit">
```

```
<%@ page import = "dem.hashmap"%>  <!-- //importing java class -->
<% 
hashmap hm = new hashmap();  /*  creating reference for my java class */
String inputvalue = request.getParameter("word"); 
String output = hm.dircreation(inputvalue);    /* calling java method */
out.println(inputvalue);
%>

</body>
</html>
```

my hashmap .java class:

```
package dem;

import java.io.File;


public class hashmap {

String nav;


public String dircreation(String dir)
{

    System.out.println("The Value is--------->"+dir);
    boolean success = false;

    File directory = new File(dir);
    System.out.println("1....The Value is--------->"+dir);
    if (directory.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Directory already exists ...");

    } else {
        System.out.println("Directory not exists, creating now");

        success = directory.mkdir();
        if (success) {
        System.out.printf("Successfully created new directory : %s%n", dir);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("Failed to create new directory: %s%n", dir);
        }
    }

    return nav;

}

 }
```